# Weighted averaging of polynomial coefficients

Tags: functions, polynomials

Suppose there are three polynomials $$y_1 = a_0 + a_1x_1, $$ $$y_2 = b_0 + b_1x_2, $$ $$y_3 = c_0 + c_1x_3,$$

and define $$ x_{\rm avg} \triangleq \dfrac{x_1(x_2-x_3)^2+x_2(x_1-x_3)^2+x_3(x_1-x_2)^2}{(x_1-x_2)^2+(x_1-x_3)^2+(x_2-x_3)^2}, $$
$$ y_{\rm avg} \triangleq \dfrac{y_1(y_2-y_3)^2+y_2(y_1-y_3)^2+y_3(y_1-y_2)^2}{(y_1-y_2)^2+(y_1-y_3)^2+(y_2-y_3)^2}. $$

I want to find $d_0 = f(a_0,b_0,c_0,a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $d_1 = f(a_0,b_0,c_0,a_1,b_1,c_1)$ such that $$y_{\rm avg} = d_0 + d_1x_{\rm avg}.$$

Is this possible? I would guess yes, but I'm not really sure. If it is, how should I solve for $d_0,d_1$ and does the solution extend to higher order polynomials? I've tried substituting the polynomials $y_1,y_2,y_3$ into the $y_{\rm avg}$ equation, but I'm unsure how to extract meaningful coefficients that are independent of $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Comment: Are $y_i$ always linear or was that just an example? Can they be higher order polynomials?

Comment: @jam just an example, I'm trying to do this with cubic polynomials so I really need to solve for $d_0,d_1,d_2$, and $d_3$.

Comment: So the form would be cubic for the individual polynomials and the "combined" polynomial would be $y_{\rm avg} = d_0 + d_1x_{\rm avg} + d_2x_{\rm avg}^2 + d_3x_{\rm avg}^3$

Comment: Personally, I doubt there's going to be a simple solution of $y_{\mathrm{avg}}$ in terms of $x_{\mathrm{avg}}$ because that algebra's going to get complicated very quickly and it's asking quite a lot to put that in the $x_\mathrm{avg}$ form. But I may well be wrong. It might be easier to try expanding $y_\mathrm{avg}$ as a multivariable function of $x_i$ and then relating that to $x_\mathrm{avg}$.

Comment: Right, the the algebra is complicated enough with just linear polynomials, with cubic ones it's outright heinous. I tried expanding $y_{\rm avg}$ as a function of $x_i$ but nothing revealed itself. Maybe I'll try some more, thanks!

Comment: There are multivariable forms of the chain rule and Taylor series so (at least in theory) you could show that if $y_\mathrm{avg}=\sum_{i,j,k}a_{ijk}x_1^ix_2^jx_3^k$ and $x_\mathrm{avg}=\sum_{i,j,k}b_{ijk}x_1^ix_2^jx_3^k$, then $y_\mathrm{avg}=\sum_n c_{n}x_{\mathrm{avg}}^n$. You could try to see if such a transformation has been previously studied. One big hurdle would be to show that $x_{\mathrm{avg}}$ is actually able to encompass all the information and 'degrees of freedom' (for lack of a better term) about $x_i$. There are many more $a_{ijk}$ than $c_n$, so can they actually be condensed?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a counterexample. Assuming $x_{\rm avg} = M$ on the diagonal $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = M$, then $y_{\rm avg} = d_0 + d_1 x_{\rm avg} = d_0 + d_1 M$, for some fixed $M$. For simplicity, fix $a_0 = 1, b_0 = 0, c_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1, b_1 = 2, c_1 = 3$.

If $M = 0$ then $y_{\rm avg} = 0 = d_0$. If $M = 1$ then $y_{\rm avg} = 2 = d_1$, but if $M = 2$ then $y_{\rm avg} \approx 3.86 \neq 2d_1$.

Comment: Why was I downvoted? I just gave an example of 3 polynomials for which $y_{\text{avg}} \neq d_0 + d_1 x_{\text{avg}}$ on the diagonal. You can even show explicitly $y_{\text{avg}}$ simplifies to $(x(12x^2-13x+5))/(2(3x^2-3x+1))$ which is clearly not a linear function of $x = x_{\text{avg}}$.